# How to check that CNG Windows API returns algorithm implementation which is FIPS compliant

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, fips

I am calling Windows CNG API (bcrypt.dll) on a host where FIPS mode is enabled.
The fact that FIPS is enabled is confirmed by the result of the function BCryptGetFipsAlgorithmMode.

How can I ensure that the returned implementation of an algorithm by the API is FIPS compliant?

It looks that just enabling the FIPS mode on the host does not guarantee the API to prevent from non-FIPS compliant algorithms instantiation, because I can successfully get MD5 hash algorithm (which is known not to be FIPS compliant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KB 811833 says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/811833/system-cryptography-use-fips-compliant-algorithms-for-encryption-hashi)

> This policy is only advisory to applications. Therefore, if you enable the policy, it does not make sure that all applications will comply. The following of areas in the operating system will be affected by this setting:

and goes on to list things affected by the policy. This includes SChannel and .NET but not the CNG API itself. [This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2005/05/16/enforcing-fips-certified-cryptography/) confirms the .NET behavior but it can be overridden with `enforceFIPSPolicy` in the app config file.

When calling `BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider` you can force the provider by specifying `MS_PRIMITIVE_PROVIDER`.

Comment: Is it documented anywhere that passing MS_PRIMITIVE_PROVIDER flag will return FIPS compliant implementations?

Comment: Ok, I see that this is what .NET Framework does to get FIPS compliant implementations. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Security/Cryptography/BCryptNative.cs,207

Comment: No it is not documented anywhere but the Vista+ implementation is FIPS compliant. "CNG Algorithm Identifiers" on MSDN notes the standard it adheres to.